# Cassandra: Set hostname as eth1 address

Tags: cassandra

I am setting up a Cassandra Cluster. I have to set the following configuration to the host ip in the subnet (e.g. 10.1.0.2):

```
    listen_address: <host ip>
    broadcast_rpc_address: <host ip>
```

and also in the environment shell file I have to add:

`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<host ip>"`

How can I set this up in another way in which whenever I deploy an image instance, these settings are set automatically?

Does it have to be set programmatically on a boot basis? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

From the `cassandra.yaml` about `listen_address`:

> Leaving it blank leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This
>   will always do the Right Thing *if* the node is properly configured
>   (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the
>   address associated with the hostname (it might not be).

For `broadcast_rpc_address`:

> Leaving this blank will set it to the same value as listen_address

I would say the answer to your question is to leave both values blank and instead set up your hosts properly (DNS entry, /etc/hosts, etc.).